# Move Saturday into Friday then AVG

Tags: t-sql

I've got a table I'm working with that is about 165M rows of data - Working on creating an average daily usage, but only for the working week.  I need to take the inventory transactions from Saturday and count them in Friday and take the Sunday moved into Monday.

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [ITEMID] nvarchar(20), [Daily Usage] decimal(38,10), [CalendarDate] date )
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( N'A24519-01', 0.0000000000, N'2019-02-18T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 7.0000000000, N'2019-02-19T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 10.0000000000, N'2019-02-20T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 4.0000000000, N'2019-02-21T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 11.0000000000, N'2019-02-22T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 0.0000000000, N'2019-02-23T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 0.0000000000, N'2019-02-24T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 9.0000000000, N'2019-02-25T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 5.0000000000, N'2019-02-26T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 8.0000000000, N'2019-02-27T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 17.0000000000, N'2019-02-28T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 0.0000000000, N'2019-03-01T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 1.0000000000, N'2019-03-02T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 0.0000000000, N'2019-03-03T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 1.0000000000, N'2019-03-04T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 12.0000000000, N'2019-03-05T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 4.0000000000, N'2019-03-06T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 14.0000000000, N'2019-03-07T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 0.0000000000, N'2019-03-08T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 0.0000000000, N'2019-03-09T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 0.0000000000, N'2019-03-10T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 4.0000000000, N'2019-03-11T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 9.0000000000, N'2019-03-12T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 6.0000000000, N'2019-03-13T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 0.0000000000, N'2019-03-14T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 14.0000000000, N'2019-03-15T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 1.0000000000, N'2019-03-16T00:00:00' ), 
( N'A24519-01', 0.0000000000, N'2019-03-17T00:00:00' )
```

So if I run the below on the above I get 4.89

```
SELECT AVG(1 * [Daily Usage]) 
FROM #temptable
```

I'm trying to get 6.85 - I don't how to move the number from Sat/Sun into the Fri/Mon - them remove the weekends from the #temptable

Comment: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`. That and a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same issue and comes here - below it what I ended up using in production of this problem.

```
--Move Saturday data into Friday and move Sunday data into Monday (Working days for buyers...)
UPDATE
    EDU
SET
    EDU.[Daily Usage] = EDU.[Daily Usage] + ND.[Daily Usage]
FROM #ExplodedDailyUsage                                    AS EDU
INNER JOIN (SELECT
                t.ITEMID
              , t.[Daily Usage]
              , t.CalendarDate
              , DATEPART(dw, t.CalendarDate)                                                                             DOW
              , DATEADD(
                    DAY, CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, t.CalendarDate) WHEN 7 THEN -1 WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, t.CalendarDate) AS NewDate
            FROM #ExplodedDailyUsage AS t
            WHERE DATEPART(dw, t.CalendarDate) IN ( 7, 1 )) ND ON ND.NewDate = EDU.CalendarDate
                                                                  AND ND.ITEMID = EDU.ITEMID;

--Delete Saturdays and Sundays
DELETE FROM #ExplodedDailyUsage WHERE DATEPART(dw, CalendarDate) IN ( 7, 1 );
```

Comment: What is the benefit of comparing the result from `DatePart` to both strings (`DATEPART(dw, t.CalendarDate) = '7'`) and integers (`DATEPART(dw, CalendarDate) IN ( 7, 1 )`)? A _simple case_ would be a little tidier. ([Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking -

Comment: `7` is an `int`. `'7'` is a `VarChar` because it is enclosed in quotation marks. Your code carefully compares the result of `DatePart` to both values. Why? As for the `case`, you could write `DateAdd( day, case DatePart( weekday, t.CalendarDate ) when 7 then -1 when 1 then 1 else 0 end, t.CalendarDate ) as NewDate` thus avoiding multiple `DatePart` and `DateAdd` calls.

Comment: Got it - I understand now, I'm a Supply Chain Manager - not a SQL Developer. . . Still learning, thanks for the feedback!!!